# Whats wrong with 'react-redux.connect()' parameters?

Tags: react-native, redux, expo

Moving sample redux app from react to react-native.
If I pass non-empty params to react-redux 'connect' function app will crash with

- on snack with message about parameter is not a function
- on real device (android) about context is text and should be placed in 'Text' component

Simular code works fine on react.
On react native sample - 'connect' with empty parameters will not crash - props just will be empty

Full sample here: https://snack.expo.io/@aaronright/reduxtests

Comment: Seems like the Android version of your snack works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this change to your snack, and it seems to run fine on the ios/android simulators.

```
const actions = {
  changeFirstName: actionChangeFirstName,
  changeSecondName: actionChangeSecondName,
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch) });

const AppComponent = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(App);
```

I also added `onChangeText={(text) => this.props.actions.changeSecondName(text)}` to your text inputs, changing Second to First for the first name input, so that they would update state. Everything is working for me on those two simulators.

That being said, what exactly is the issue you are having? Connect requires the first param, mapStateToProps, to function, but does not require the second param, `mapDispatchToProps`. You can pass `lodash._` for the first param if you really dont need it

Comment: Thank you. Android version generated by snack started to works
Web view still runs with error, but alright I will not trust snack in testing things